# How do I install Ductilcad with Draftsight?

Tags: files

Is it possible to install `ductilcad` with `draftsight`?

Is there any other program with pipe acessóries (like ductilcad) that is compatible with darftsight?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunetly You can't but you can use Blender instead with Ductilcad .
The Exported dxfs are fully compatible with Blender 2.49b